# Does numpy.argsort() increase (a lot) the size of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy.array` called `combinations` (2D array of 336^3=37,933,056 by 3 `np.float32`), and also an `err_np` (1D array of 336^3=37,933,056 `np.float16`), storing the %error of each 3 value combination.

I need to sort `combinations` by their absolute error, so i do:

```
from sys import getsizeof as size
import numpy as np

# Some stuff gets done here

print(size(combinations)) # 120 - **EITHER THIS IS TOO LOW**
print(len(combinations))  # 37,933,056
print(combinations)       # array OK

combinations = combinations[abs(err_np).argsort()] 

print(size(combinations)) # 455,196,792 - **OR THIS IS TOO HIGH**
print(len(combinations))  # 37,933,056
print(combinations)       # array sorted OK
```

I assumed the size before sorting was wrong, but i remind you `size()` is `sys.getsizeof()`, and the whole array is in there...

Is there a way to sort an `np.array` using less memory? It should also be as time-efficient as possible, since the size of the array. I currently `del err_np` after sorting `combinations` so i don't care about it.

Answer (score 1):

So `combinations` is (37,933,056, 3) shape array.  `len()` only displays the first dimension.

Then it's data takes up:

```
In [182]: 37933056*3*4
Out[182]: 455196672
```

bytes - that's the shape times 4 bytes per element.

From the first `size` I'd say `combinations` is a `view` of some other array.  The 120 only records the base array size, not the shared data memory.

After the sort, `combinations` is a 'copy', with its own databuffer, and `size` reports the full size.

`getsizeof` is only useful if you understand what it's reporting.  It's ok if the array is not a view, but that size can just as easily be calculated from `shape` and `dtype`.  `getsizeof` is even less useful when looking at things like lists.